# Google Maps Satellite View - Change brightness or contrast?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Maps SDK for Android.

I have noticed that some satellite images are very dark and its sometimes hard to see things.

I would like to be able to adjust brightness, contrast or perhaps some other setting in order to improve visibility in some areas on the map.

Is this possible somehow natively or do you need a library? Or is it not possible at all?